# Difference between definition of a structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

I am starting to grasp how Linked List work in C and I have a doubt about how to build a function that generate new elements for a linked list:

```
struct elem{
  int data;
  struct elem* next;
};


typedef struct elem* listEl; // we call data type pointer to an element listEl;


//how to create an element

listEl createElem1(){
  listEl temp;
  temp = malloc(sizeof(struct elem)); 

  (*temp).data = 0;
  (*temp).next = NULL;
  return temp;

}

//how to create an element

listEl createElem2(){
  listEl temp;
  temp = malloc(sizeof(struct elem*)); ////

  (*temp).data = 0;
  (*temp).next = NULL;
  return temp;

}
```

Here we have defined an element of a linked list as a structure with an integer and a pointer to another element of a linked list.

The other two functions are needed to generate new pointer to elements. Since we want to generate a new element, should we use to allocate the relevant memory for our element the function `"malloc(sizeof(struct elem))"` while on the other hand the function `malloc(sizeof(struct elem*));` would be an error, since we are allocating the size of a pointer and not the size of a struct?

I am asking this since in one of the lectures I am following about this topic a function to create new element has been defined in the second way and it seemed to me not correct.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The second function is indeed incorrect, although neither of them is fully correct, since they don't set `next` to `NULL` but instead assign to `data` twice

Comment: I think `(*temp).data = NULL;`  should be `(*temp).next = NULL;`.

Comment: Thanks to both. Edited

Comment: @PwNzDust, curious, who or what text suggested making type `typedef struct elem* listEl;`?

Comment: It is very poor form to hide pointer nature behind a typedef such as `listEl`.  Doing so is almost always more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis is correct:

This is incorrect:

```
temp = malloc(sizeof(struct elem*));
```

Because it allocates space for a pointer to the struct, not the struct itself.  Subsequently attempting to dereference `temp` and read/write the fields will trigger undefined behavior because doing so would read or write past the end of allocated memory.

So this is correct:

```
temp = malloc(sizeof(struct elem));
```

Or better yet:

```
temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
```

Because it doesn't depend on the name of the type of `temp`.

Comment: UV the better yet: `temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);`

Answer (score 1):

To create a new element of the list you need to create an object of the type

```
struct elem{
  int data;
  struct elem* next;
};
```

So you need to allocate dynamically a memory that will contain such an object. Thus you need to write

```
temp = malloc(sizeof(struct elem));
```

The function can be more safer if it will check whether a memory for an element of the list was successfully allocated. Also the function should accept the value that will be assigned to the created node of the list.

That is the function should be  defined the following way

```
listEl createElem1( int data )
{
    listEl temp = malloc( sizeof( *temp ) ); 

    if ( temp != NULL )
    {
        temp->data = data;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of a pointer just holds the value of the address. The size of the struct will be dependent on the data it holds

The size of your struct will remain the same.
If you're creating a new struct you can do something like:

```
struct elem *temp= malloc(sizeof(struct elem));
```

and it will allocate the proper amount of memory

Comment: I don't follow.  On one hand, you say that pointer types may have different sizes in different C implementations.  This is true, but not particularly relevant to the question.  On the other hand, you seem to be saying that the size of the struct type will be the same on all implementations. This is definitely false, but also not particularly relevant to the question.  I think you might have a point somewhere in there that is both valid and relevant, but that's unclear from current prose.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I stated that doing `sizeof(type*)` is just going to give you the size of a pointer (which will be 2, 4, or 8 bytes depending on the OS), while `sizeof(struct ex)` will return the size of the struct. OP is asking why he can't do `sizeof(type*)` so I tried to answer his question, which wasn't asked clearly in the first place.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).